# How to add multiple leads to particular campaign in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online, lead

i tried to add multiple leads to campaign using marketing list and it works fine. But i need to add directly from lead s Homepage by selecting multiple leads, is it possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can only create a **quick campaign** for multiple selected leads in any lead view (e.g. homepage), not a campaign. The campaign could be only associated to one or more marketing lists.